# Understanding Grizzly 1.9.36 internals

Tags: configuration, glassfish-3, grizzly

I enabled the "SNOOP" configuration (under Transports -> tcp) on the admin webpage to see what grizzly is doing under the hood. As soon as I applied the changes, the below was printed in server.log . From the log, I fail to understand why Grizzly initializes it configuration again on changing just one parameter (that too SNOOP). The way I interpret that Grizzly has initialized itself is by the following line written in the server.log. Is this just bad logging or something I am interpreting incorrectly. Why would the framework create the HTTP listener again just on change of one parameter.

```
WEB0169: Created **HTTP listener** [http-listener-1] on host/port
```

Full log below

```
  [#|2015-06-09T15:10:01.189+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=62;_ThreadName=pool-78-thread-1;|WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-1] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8080]|#]

    [#|2015-06-09T15:10:01.202+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=63;_ThreadName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|Grizzly Framework 1.9.36 started in: 6ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]|#]

    [#|2015-06-09T15:10:01.981+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=62;_ThreadName=pool-78-thread-1;|WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-2] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8181]|#]

    [#|2015-06-09T15:10:02.003+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=64;_ThreadName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|Grizzly Framework 1.9.36 started in: 5ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8181]|#]

    [#|2015-06-09T15:10:02.313+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=62;_ThreadName=pool-78-thread-1;|WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-download-listener-1] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8585]|#]

    [#|2015-06-09T15:10:02.329+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=65;_ThreadName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|Grizzly Framework 1.9.36 started in: 5ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8085]|#]

    [#|2015-06-09T15:10:03.250+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=62;_ThreadName=pool-78-thread-1;|WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-1] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8080]|#]

    [#|2015-06-09T15:10:03.259+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=66;_ThreadName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|Grizzly Framework 1.9.36 started in: 3ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]|#]

    [#|2015-06-09T15:10:04.018+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=62;_ThreadName=pool-78-thread-1;|WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-2] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8181]|#]

    [#|2015-06-09T15:10:04.035+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=67;_ThreadName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|Grizzly Framework 1.9.36 started in: 4ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8181]|#]

    [#|2015-06-09T15:10:04.342+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=62;_ThreadName=pool-78-thread-1;|WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-download-listener-1] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8585]|#]

    [#|2015-06-09T15:10:04.355+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=68;_ThreadName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|Grizzly Framework 1.9.36 started in: 2ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8585]|#]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potential change to a transport may impact all http-listeners running on top of the transport.

Comment: So very specifically in this case does it reinitialize the listeners in a service affecting way?

Comment: AFAIR network layer will be definitely restarted, as for the web layer - I'm not sure, it's better to double check that.